# Find last commit node for file included in a tag

Tags: git, tags

I have a situation in git where I want to walk the revisions of a file after it was tagged. However, the file itself was not changed in the commit node that was tagged.

Is there a way to figure out the last commit node in which the file was changed before the tag's commit node?

By the way, I can't just look at the overall differences since the tag because the log messages contain other important pieces of information I need (references to issue tracking numbers).

Comment: Something like `git log -n1 --follow <tag> -- <path>` should do the trick.

Comment: @Jubobs That seems to do the trick. Go ahead and post as an answer so you can get the credit. By the way, the `--` between `<tag>` and `<path>` seem to be optional. Is it?

Comment: It *is* optional but it's a good idea.  Consider `git log ... a b ...`.  Is `a` a tag or a path?  How about `b`?  Certainly the last word in `git log -n1 README` looks like a path, but what if someone did `git tag README`?

Comment: @NJones Good. I'm pretty confident that your question is a duplicate, though... If I fail to find a relevant question, I'll write an answer.